# Python import文で最上位のディレクトリからの書き方

Tags: python

プロジェクトとかの規約で最上位の階層を含めたimport文の書き方について質問します。
以下は例です。

```
/root_package ※importをここからにしたい
 | start.py
 | const.py ※XYZ=(1, 0, 0)といった定義
 | 
 /utils
  | u.py
  | uconst.py ※ABC=(1, 2, 3)といった定義
```

start.py

```py
from root_package.const import XYZ
```

u.py

```py
from root_package.utils.uconst import ABC
```

例は省略していますが"＿init＿.py"は各フォルダに中身は空であります。
以上のように、start.pyとu.pyで最上位の"root_package"を含めた記述で
from import記述で問題ないと思うのですが、
start.pyを実行すると"ModuleNotFoundError XYZ"が出ます。
何か記述が足らないのでしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事を読み解くと何か分かるかもしれません。[\[Python\]自作のモジュール・パッケージのimport](https://fuji-pocketbook.net/selfmade-modules/), [Pythonインポート周り徹底理解への道](https://qiita.com/papi_tokei/items/bc34d798dc7a6d49df30), [pythonのimport文・パッケージ化について](https://qiita.com/shotoyoo/items/4b3fcacfef997d51cee5), [pythonのパッケージ階層の話](https://qiita.com/arc279/items/885af7d3f6ac36a75c00), [Pythonでパッケージをimportする際のテクニックについて](https://www.ipride.co.jp/blog/2449), [Python でモジュール／パッケージを作成する](https://maku77.github.io/python/env/create-module.html) あるいは省略した部分が問題かもしれないので、全ての内容をそのまま質問に記述してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ディレクトリ構造の説明が間違っていて正しい質問になっていないと思います。（ディレクトリ構造の引用が間違っているか、エラーの引用が間違っているか、どちらの可能性が高いかと考えると前者と判断しました）もっと簡単な例を作って"実際に動かした結果"で質問した方がよいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

実行するプログラムの置き場所が間違っているようですね。

`start.py`が実行するプログラムであるなら、それはパッケージに含まれるファイルではなくアプリケーションなので`root_package`ディレクトリの中にあるのはおかしいでしょう。

`start.py`は以下のように`root_package`の親ディレクトリに配置すべきものでしょうね。

```
start.py
/root_package ※importをここからにしたい
  | __init__.py
  | const.py ※XYZ=(1, 0, 0)といった定義
  | 
  /utils
    | __init__.py
    | u.py
    | uconst.py ※ABC=(1, 2, 3)といった定義
```